# What is in a http body?

Tags: http, https

I've searched on google for an explanation but I couldn't find one.
What is actually in an http body and how do I use a http body?
What kind of data is in a http body and what does it do?

Answer (score 2):

The message body of an HTTP Request is an array of bytes which may not be present depending on the response code ([RFC2616 Message Body](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.3)).

HTTP is a protocol for sending messages, the message body contains the content of this messages.

The kind of content is defined by [Message Headers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-7.1) it can be anything mostly it will be text or images.

I think [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) is a good starting point to understand how HTTP works.

Comment: Please be more specific, if this is a different question you should open a new Question with more details.

Comment: like what is the website used for, it looks confusing.

Comment: I don't know much about IETF so I don't know why this confusing page. It's an organization that promotes Internet standards see [Wikipedia IETF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Engineering_Task_Force).
Their standards are widely agreed on, thats why I used them as reference.